# Stripe "Upgrade" from a TRIAL non-zero price to a ZERO price without trial and without credit card

Tags: python, stripe-payments, payment, subscription

I'm new to Stripe integrations and I've been struggling now for some days trying to figure out the correct flow for my usecase.

I have a product which people can subscribe.

Initially I'm providing a NON-Zero Price with a trial.
Depending on the user, I would like to allow him to change to a ZERO Price.

My original subscription is created like this:

```
await stripeInstance.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
created as well)
      items: [{ price: <<PRICE_ID>> }],
      trial_settings: {
        end_behavior: {
          missing_payment_method: "cancel",
        },
      },
      trial_period_days: 30,
      payment_settings: {
        save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
      }
    });
```

As you noticed, it is configured to cancel the Subscription when it gets to the end of the Trial Period and the user did not provided a payment method.

In this situation where the client supposed to be able to change to a free price, Credit Card doesn't supposed to be requested at all.

When user tries to upgrade from this Trial plan to the free one, I'm hitting the API like this on my python backend:

```py
stripe.Subscription.modify(<<SUB_ID>>, items=[{"id": <<ITEM_ID>>, "price": <<NEW_PRICE_ID>>}], payment_settings={"save_default_payment_method": "off"}, trial_end: "now")
```

This is causing my subscription to be cancelled. I now that I could been creating a new Subscription and delete the old one, but I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the same behavior (Sub is cancelled). You may want to write to Stripe Support with concrete Ids so they can investigate and assist.